# What is the best SQL Server field type to cast to when storing a UNC path stored in a sql_variant field?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, datatypes, fields

What is the best choice of field type to cast to when storing a UNC path in a `sql_variant` in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

It appears that I could store up to 4000 characters according to [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Windows Dev Centre at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) seems to suggest that 260 characters will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path is being stored in a `SQL_VARIANT` field, then you might as well `CAST` / `CONVERT` to `NVARCHAR(4000)` on the way out as that is the most that can be stored by a `SQL_VARIANT`. While the *typical* upper limit for a path is 260 characters, it is possible to exceed that and go up to 32,767 characters (even if that is unlikely to happen in practice). Since this scenario concerns storing the value in a local variable or returning in a result set (as opposed to how it is stored in the table), there is no reason to use less than 4000, and no use in specifying `MAX` since the value stored in the table couldn't hold that data anyway.

However, *why* would a path be stored as a `SQL_VARIANT` in the first place? Even if the total length never exceeds even the default 260 characters, it would still be best to store as `NVARCHAR(500)`, or `NVARCHAR(1000)`, or something like that.

Comment: Curious, can you explain how to exceed that 260 character default?

Comment: @Skagalak Yes. As explained in the MSDN documentation linked in the question, you would use the `\\?\ ` prefix. Examples taken from that same page are: `"\\?\D:\very long path"` and `"\\?\UNC\server\share"`.